# Integer by itself in a javascript file

Tags: javascript

I found a typo in one of my javascript files where there was an integer just sitting on a line on its own with nothing else.  The file never errored out because of it so I was wondering, how does javascript handle or evaluate a line with just an integer on it and nothing else 'behind the scenes'?

Answer (score 2):

The following is a valid statement:

```
4;
```

Of course, it would make more sense to do something like `var num = 4;`, but what you're doing above is the same thing, you're just not saving it's return value to a variable.

You can even have completely empty statements. The following is a valid, empty statement:

```
;
```

So you could have a program that looks like this:

```
var num = 4;
4;
;
```

Each of those lines would be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Well, "5" is a code, that returns 5. You can try it out by opening Chrome Dev Tools (Press F12), then open console and enter a number. It will return a number, so it is valid piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can write any expression in a line, in fact, it is referenced an `ExpressionStatement` in the grammar. So the line `4;` is a statement, which evaluates, but never sotres it's variable; You can even leave the semicolon in most cases because of *Automatic Semicolon Insertion*.

These statements get evaluated, but then the resulting value is ignored, meaning that single number or string literals will not have any side effect (like `1+2+3;`). However, calling functions or accessing variables or fields can have side effects (like: `1+a()+b)`, a gets accessed and called, b gets accessed).

But there are special cases, like `"use strict";`, which old engines just skip over as it is just a *StringLiteral* inside an *ExpressionStatement*, but modern browsers notice this line, and switch to strict mode.

Comment: There will be a side effect (error), if a single expression is a variable name, which is not declared.

Comment: @Teemu: and there are side effects when you write an IIFE, which is also an *ExpressionStatement*. You are right that you can use it to have side effects, that's why i said "in most of the time"